# Does StringBuilder need ToString()

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

This should hopefully be a quick one. I have a StringBuilder like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

I append to my StringBuilder like so:

```
sb.Append("Foo");
sb.Append("Bar");
```

I then want to make this equal to a string variable. Do I do this like so:

```
string foobar = sb;
```

Or like so:

```
string foobar = sb.ToString();
```

Is the former being lazy or the latter adding more code than is necessary?

Thanks

Comment: Apologies, thought the same principles applied to both!

Comment: What's lazy is you couldn't just try both and see that one doesn't work -1

Comment: To be fair I asked because I was using a StreamWriter and noticed it worked with or without .ToString(), I didn't think that this might be an overload of the StreamWriter method

Comment: I see, well in that case leave the `ToString()` off when calling. At worst the overload will call it for you and at best it might have some clever optimisation. But either way the language designers added the overload for your benefit, so might as well use it.

Comment: You cant implicitly convert from `StreamWriter` to a `string` either. And calling `.ToString()` wont give you the content of the writer.

Comment: @Magnus he means he is calling the `StreamWriter.Write(object value)` method. With a `StringBuilder` as his `value`.

Comment: I personally would have preferred if the compiler just worked the conversion magic behind the scenes, but that wasn't what was done.   I suppose purists wouldn't want to do subtle behind-the-scenes-conversions, although having to convert 'cat' to 'cat' seems overboard to me!  Also, despite this question seeming simplistic, it actually has brought forth a lot of good discussion anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Java, you can't define implicit conversions between types anyway, beyond what's in the specification - so you can't convert from `StringBuilder` to `String` anyway; you have to call `toString()`.

In C# there *could* be an implicit user-defined conversion between `StringBuilder` and `String` (defined in either `StringBuilder` or `String`), but there isn't - so you still have to call `ToString()`.

In both cases you will get a compile-time error if you *don't* call the relevant method.

Answer (score 7):

In C# you need to use `string foobar = sb.ToString();` or you will get an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to 'string'`

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `string foobar = sb;` won't compile. You have to use `String foobar = stringBuilder.toString();`

Answer (score 2):

You could have tested it before asking... You would have seen that

```
string foobar = sb;
```

doesn't compile (C#).

Use `sb.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String foobar = sb.ToString();
```

should be used. As this will convert the `StringBuilder` to `String` and then assign the value.

Using    string foobar = sb;    will give you a compile time error "Cannot implicitly convert type  to "

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are correct, just to clarify some things. `StringBuilder` is not a `String`'s subclass so you can't cast from `StringBuilder` to `String`. `StringBuilder`'s `toString()` method produces a `String` object, so you should use it to "cast" from `StringBuilder` to `String`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When converting to `String` use `toString` in Java. (`ToString` in C#)

Answer (score 1):

**ToString() in [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29)** required to convert to String.

```
String str=sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java all objects have toString(), inherited from Object superclass. StringBuilder (SB) is mutable, String is not. Assigning SB (Mutable) to String (immutable) needs to copy the internal char buffer and return an immutable String instance.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers are correct. However, wanted to highlight another usage, which, in some scenarios can be useful. When converting to string we can use built-in static functions/utilities e.g.

C#

```
string str = Convert.ToString(sb);
```

Java

```
String str = String.valueOf(sb);
```

This is particularly useful when input "sb" can be null, but, code wants to handle it gracefully without raising a NullPointerException and avoids code like:

```
if (sb == null) 
   return "null";
else
   return sb.toString()
```